# Bootstrap - Background image not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My CSS markup:

```
.rowbgi {
    background-image:url('img/gradient.png');
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

My HTML markup:

```
    <div class="span4 rowbgi">
      <img class="img-circle" data-src="holder.js/140x140">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Stack Overflow</p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details </a></p>
    </div><!-- /.span4 -->
```

I am not able to see the background image, but the color is seen in the background. The image is available in the path.

Can somebody tell me some silly mistake I am doing?

Comment: what does your web inspector indicate?

Comment: What did you do at last?

Answer (score 12):

Nobody knows what you are doing, because you did not show it (eg. with jsfiddle ;P), but my first guess is that you have following file structure:

- HTML file in root directory: `/index.html`,
- CSS file in css directory: `/css/style.css`,
- images in `/img/gradient.png`.

Now, mind that all the files linked from HTML/CSS have paths relative to them. So, if you keep CSS in `/css`, then the path in CSS `img/xxx` links to `/css/img/xxx`. If I am guessing correctly and this is your case change the style to:

```
background-image:url(/img/gradient.png);
```

or

```
background-image:url(../img/gradient.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried using the image path format, but the image wasn't showing up at all.

But when I uploaded the image to my server, and I'm assuming this would work with any image hosting platform, like Imgur, and used the full path, it worked.

So, instead of using:

```
background-image: url('img/gradient.png');
```

Do:

```
background-image: url('https://example.com/img/gradient.png');
```

Hopefully, this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

To use CSS to load the image, you will have to save the image file inside your CSS folder (if using an external style sheet). If you use the url `image.jpg` for example, CSS is looking for that file inside the CSS folder. Your CSS markup is telling CSS that there is a sub-folder called `img` inside your CSS folder, which probably isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

convert your png to file to jpg and Paste the same line after opening the body tag in the html code

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Can you share proper detail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

background: url("../images/name of image") fixed center;